# PHPUnit : test that a function is called only once

Tags: php, phpunit

With PHPUnit, I want to test that a function is called only once in Mocked Class. I tested several cases to be sure to understand `excepts()` :

`functionInMock` is not executed (**Ok, expected result : no error**) :

```
$myMock
    ->expects($this->never())
    ->method('functionInMock')
;
```

`functionInMock` is executed 1 times (**Ok, expected result : no error**) :

```
$myMock
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('functionInMock')
;
```

`functionInMock` is executed 2 times (**Ok, expected result : error**) :

```
$myMock
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('functionInMock')
;
```

`functionInMock` is executed 1 time :

```
$myMock
    ->expects($this->exactly(2))
    ->method('functionInMock')
;

or

$myMock
    ->expects($this->exactly(999))
    ->method('functionInMock')
;
```

Why don't I have an error in this last case ? The test passes without reporting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I am no sure why you have unexpected behaviour but this example works fine

```
<?php

// Lets name it 'SampleTest.php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSample(): void
    {
        $myMock = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(Sample::class)
            ->addMethods(['functionInMock'])
            ->getMock();
        $myMock
            ->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('functionInMock');
        $myMock->functionInMock();
    }
}

class Sample
{
    public function function2InMock(): void
    {
    }
}
```

Execution

```
$ phpunit SampleTest.php 
PHPUnit 9.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 125 ms, Memory: 6.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) SampleTest::testSample
Expectation failed for method name is "functionInMock" when invoked 2 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 2 times, actually called 1 times.

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```